# Get all dates in a array between selecteddaterange from ngxdaterangepicker calendar in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore

Here's what I tried. I want to get dates between selected enddate and startdate in an array. So that I can plot the graph between dates and number of calls .

```
enumerateDaysBetweenDates(startDate, endDate) {
    const dates = [];
    const currDate = moment(startDate).startOf('day');
    const lastDate = moment(endDate).startOf('day');

    while(currDate.add(1, 'days').diff(lastDate) < 0) {
        dates.push(currDate.clone().toDate());
    }
    console.log(dates[0]);
    return dates;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the function like that

```
function enumerateDaysBetweenDates(startDate, endDate) {
    let dates = [];
    while(startDate.getTime() <= endDate.getTime()) {
        let initDate = new Date(startDate);
        dates.push(initDate.getDay() + '/' + (initDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + initDate.getYear());       
        startDate.setTime(startDate.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000); // adding one day
    }
    return dates;
}
```

and use it like this

```
enumerateDaysBetweenDates(new Date('2019-11-12'),new Date('2019-11-20'));
```

and its result will be

```
0: Tue Nov 12 2019 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00) {}
1: Wed Nov 13 2019 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00) {}
2: Thu Nov 14 2019 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00) {}
3: Fri Nov 15 2019 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00) {}
4: Sat Nov 16 2019 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00) {}
5: Sun Nov 17 2019 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00) {}
6: Mon Nov 18 2019 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00) {}
7: Tue Nov 19 2019 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00) {}
8: Wed Nov 20 2019 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00) {}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for this, but I want these dates in dd/mm/yy format only. Thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

Use this https://github.com/rotaready/moment-range

```
import { extendMoment } from 'moment-range';  
const range = moment.range(start, end);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for moment, use Array.from with a length of how many days you want and a constructor function that adds the index to start date.

```js
const msInDay = 1000 * 3600 * 24; // Number of milliseconds in a day

const enumerateDaysBetweenDates = (startDate, endDate) => Array.from(
  { length: (endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / msInDay + 1 },
  (_, index) => new Date(startDate.getTime() + (index * msInDay))
);

console.log(enumerateDaysBetweenDates(new Date('2019-01-23'), new Date('2019-01-28')));
```

Moment is quite a bloated library and it is not tree shakable so you get the lot even if you use a very small part of the library. It is also not functional so

```
currDate.add(1, 'days')
```

mutates currDate so each iteration of your loop currDate moves one day ahead. You need to clone currDate on each loop.